# Windows 7 Guest doesn't finish installing nor boot in KVM / libvirt on 16.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using QEMU/KVM with libvirt and Virtual Machine Manager as GUI.

I want to install Windows 7 Professional SP01 (64Bit) in a VM. I have a regular .iso installation image and, of course, a valid activation key.

The process always ends with the VM Manager consoles showing a black screen which says `Starting Windows...` but then nothing else happens anymore. That means, Windows 7 never finishes the installation in my VM.

I don't know how to show the VM settings I've chosen here. If GUI screenshots are appropriate, please let me know.

I've set up a `VirtIO Disk 1` device which has a source path to a virtio driver .iso image (`~/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.126.iso`). This VirtIO Disk is also set as boot device.

When I choose `Force Reset` from the VM manager menu, the Guest console says:

```
SeaBios (version Ubuntu-1.8.2-1ubuntu1)
Machine UUID ...

iPXE (http://ipxe.org) ....


Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk

No bootable device.
```

So, what can I do to get Win7 running as a KVM Guest?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me it helped to switch the display from "default" to "cirrus". Found that on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620152/kvm-install-windows7-stop-at-starting-windows).